# How to create a Scroll Sidebar in a component in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs

I hope you're all doing well.

I'm facing a small issue with React.js. Earlier this afternoon, I had a scrollbar in my personalized Component Sidebar.

I would like my Sidebar to stay fixed, but only if my Sidebar has many tabs. It should create a scroll bar inside my Sidebar component, not in my App.jsx.

I tried many things but most often, it is the scrollbar from the window that changed. I do not understand why.

My code was working fine, but for some reason, it's not working anymore, and I've tried several solutions without success.

Could you please help me with my code to better understand the issue?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaTh, FaBars, FaCompass, FaHouseUser, FaUserShield, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
// import { LOGO } from "./../assets/logo.jpeg";

function SideBar({ children }) {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

    const menuItems = [
        {
            name: "Dashboard",
            icon: <FaTh />,
            path: "/dashboard",
        },
        {
            name: "Detector",
            icon: <FaCompass />,
            path: "/detector",
        },
        {
            name: "Policies",
            icon: <FaUserShield />,
            path: "/policies",
        },
        {
            name: "Violation",
            icon: <FaHouseUser />,
            path: "/violation",
        },

        // //-------
        {
            name: "Dashboard",
            icon: <FaTh />,
            path: "/dashboard",
        },
        {
            name: "Detector",
            icon: <FaCompass />,
            path: "/detector",
        },
        {
            name: "Policies",
            icon: <FaUserShield />,
            path: "/policies",
        },
        {
            name: "Violation",
            icon: <FaHouseUser />,
            path: "/violation",
        },
        {
            name: "Dashboard",
            icon: <FaTh />,
            path: "/dashboard",
        },
        {
            name: "Detector",
            icon: <FaCompass />,
            path: "/detector",
        },
        {
            name: "Policies",
            icon: <FaUserShield />,
            path: "/policies",
        },
        {
            name: "Violation",
            icon: <FaHouseUser />,
            path: "/violation",
        },
        {
            name: "Dashboard",
            icon: <FaTh />,
            path: "/dashboard",
        },
        {
            name: "Detector",
            icon: <FaCompass />,
            path: "/detector",
        },
        {
            name: "Policies",
            icon: <FaUserShield />,
            path: "/policies",
        },
        {
            name: "Violation",
            icon: <FaHouseUser />,
            path: "/violation",
        },
    ];

    // const handleBarsMouseEnter = () => {
    //     console.log("Mouse over FaBars");
    // };

    // const handleTimesMouseEnter = () => {
    //     console.log("Mouse over FaTimes");
    // };

    return (
        <div className={`container ${isOpen ? "sidebar-open" : "sidebar-closed"}`}>
            <div style={{ width: isOpen ? "300px" : "50px" }} className="sidebar">
                <div className="top_section">
                    <h1 style={{ display: isOpen ? "block" : "none" }} className="logo">
                        <img className="logo-dashboard" src="/src/assets/logo.jpeg" alt="Logo" />
                    </h1>
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: isOpen ? "50px" : "0px" }} className="bars">
                        {isOpen ? (
                            // Si ouvert, afficher une croix (fermeture)
                            <FaBars onClick={toggle} />
                        ) : (
                            // Sinon, afficher un hamburger (ouverture)
                            <FaTimes onClick={toggle} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <NavLink to={item.path} activeClassName="active" key={index} className="link">
                        <div className="icon">{item.icon}</div>
                        <div style={{ display: isOpen ? "block" : "none" }} className="link_test">
                            {item.name}
                        </div>
                    </NavLink>
                ))}
            </div>
            <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SideBar;
```

my App.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.top_section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.logo-dashboard {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.bars {
    font-size: 25px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.link {
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    gap: 15px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.link:hover {
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.active {
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: #000;
}

.icon,
.link_text {
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sidebar-open ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

.sidebar-open ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.sidebar-open ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}


.sidebar-closed ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and patience

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. You need a scroll bar on your sidebar component when it has more than 'X' number of Tabs.

The way to achieve that is to set your side bar to a fixed width or heigh ( height for vertical scroll bar, width for horizontal scroll bar) and put the `overflow-x: scroll` or `overflow-y: scroll` based on which scroll you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,

Yes, thank you SOO much. It works !!! Sincerely thanks. 
I forgot to add the overflow before.

You saved my night.